# Windows 7 - Eclipse now needs me to run as administrator

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, uac

I installed Eclipse (Kepler) on this W7 64-bit machine and initially I could run it "normally" by just clicking the desktop icon or whatever.
Then I replaced the whole "workspace" directory with one from another machine (because I'm changing systems).

Now if I run Eclipse not "as administrator" it opens and will even run apps... but nothing can be saved, including changes to files and updates to the .metadata of any kind.

I changed all the "ownership" and "permissions" which could possibly be involved.  I am the only user of this machine, and I am in the administrators group.  I *CAN* still use it, if I run "as an administrator".  But I'm stumped why the UAC should have been happy to run Eclipse before without the "as 'strator" but now refuses...

Because... what I've understood about this question is that the UAC looks at apps and decides whether or not they look dodgy and on that basis decides whether you have to run "as 'strator".  So what's changed?

I have the option of uninstalling Eclipse and reinstalling it, and then incrementally adding the various project folders... fine, it *may* work. But I like to understand these things as far as is feasibly possible!

Comment: Try incrementally adding project folders to a new workspace that Kepler recognizes.  When installing a new version of Eclipse, you **must** install Eclipse to a new directory and create a new workspace.  Anything else may corrupt your projects.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc yes, went for the incremental-add in the end. Tx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Because... what I've understood about this question is that the UAC looks at apps and decides whether or not they look dodgy and on that basis decides whether you have to run "as 'strator".

UAC doesn't do anything like that. UAC is an ability of Windows to run an application as an administrator. There are three four ways an application can be run as an administrator (causing the UAC consent dialog to appear):

- you right-click the application and select "Run As Administrator"
- the application has been manifested with a `requestedExecutionLevel` of `requireAdministrator`
- the application has a filename that looks like a setup application (e.g. `setup.exe`, `install.exe`, `update.exe`), in which case the Shell opts to run it elevated just in case
- you call `ShellExecute` with the `runas` verb.

i think there's one of two things happening:

- you missed a spot, in which case you should use Process Monitor to look for `Access denied` errors
- you tried copying files to a protected location (e.g. Program Files) and they were instead redirected to:

  ```
  C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files(x86)\Eclipse
  ```

And then when you run Eclipse, the files are not there.

Again, use Process Monitor to find where Eclipse is looking for what.