# HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I made a JSP-Project in Eclipse (with Tomcat 7) but when I run the page, i get an ClassnotFoundExcption.

in my Project i work with Controllers to bind Data to the JSp with , i have a Controller, a Service and a Data-Object -> dbChanges

I hava already "google'd" my Question and didnt find anything.

PS: Sorry for bad English, i tried my best

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.dbChanges.index_jsp

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.dbChanges.index_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:177)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.dbChanges.index_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:172)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.30 logs.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/7.0.30
```

Apache Log

```
Jan 14, 2014 11:33:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
Schwerwiegend: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/dbChanges] threw exception [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:139)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:172)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>dbChanges</display-name>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>http://www.springframework.org/tags/form</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/META-INF/spring-form.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/META-INF/c.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
    </jsp-config>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>enableSessionManager</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/errors/403.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/errors/404.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <!-- <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/errors/500.html</location>
    </error-page>  -->
</web-app>
```

If you need mor Informations (Files etc.), just say it.

I hope you can help me.
Obsidianfarmer

Comment: have you added tomcat-7 jars in your project???

Comment: sry for aking :( but witch Jars do you mean, tomcat-api, tomcat-util or something else? I am a Beginner in JSP/Tomcat

Comment: just right-click your project, then go to your build-path and check if there is tomcat-7 library or not.

Comment: thx, there was a "Apache Tomcat v7.0[Apache Tomcat v7.0]" but not selected, i have selected it now but I get still this Exception :(

Comment: add you web.xml code here...

Comment: ok, I've added the xml into my Question

Comment: Is your index.jsp in your /WEB-INF directory? I seems like a path error to me...

Comment: Add the tomcat path in the configure class path  section of the project.

Answer (score 2):

1.Open command prompt using "Run as administrator" or using sudo in Linux

2. Go to the "bin" directory of Tomcat folder.
   for example: cd C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.15\bin

Note the version number and the accurate Location.

3. Run 'startup.bat' and the Server should start
4. Open a web browser entered http://localhost:8080/
5. If the server runns without exceptions, this means that you must give eclipse administrative privileges.

to do that you can visit: [Windows 7 - Eclipse now needs me to run as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442468/windows-7-eclipse-now-needs-me-to-run-as-administrator)
or https://askubuntu.com/questions/249098/how-do-i-run-eclipse-as-sudo

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because in the eclipse configuration I had the JDK folder (`jdk1.6.0_45`) set as the JRE location. Instead it should have been set to `jre6` in my "Installed JREs" preferences.

Answer (score 1):

For Java-EE projects converted to Maven project with [jstl dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2) in `pom.xml`:
In my case, I needed to add Maven dependencies to the build path

Walkthrough:

- right click the project in question
- open Properties
- click on Deployment Assembly
- click Add
- select Java Build Path Entries
- select Maven dependencies

---

Update: also check your **Execution enviroment && Workspace JRE** are correctly setup.