# Spring boot / Jsp exception - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.homePage_jsp

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, jboss

I have a SpringBoot, JSP and Maven application running on app server. I restarted the server and application stopped working. On browser it's showing 404 error. Server logs showing this exception -

`*org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.homePage_jsp*`

It seems jsp parsing exception. Can someone please guide me how to resolve this problem.

Note - Application is working fine on localhost.

I tried to redeploy the war file through jenkins. War file deployed successfully. But while hitting the application using browser, it's showing same exception.

Comment: ClassNotFoundEx with jsp means, jsp isn't compiled. You can refer to similiar issue here .  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28215974/classnotfoundexception-jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be many permutations and combinations that can produce the given problem. I am writing here, what worked for me -

I deleted the content from Apache tomcat's 1) **temp** folder and 2) **work** folder.

Then I redeployed the war file as usual and it worked!